# Perl Y axis values showing decimal

Tags: perl, graph

I have a multiple line graph thats generated by perl and looks great however, some of the values on the y axis are decimal values and some aren't. For some reason every point in 400 increments is fine but everything inbetween is a decimal value.

Any ideas?

Comment: using these mods 
use Getopt::Std;
use GD::Graph::lines;
use GD::Graph::colour; 
use GD::Graph::Data;

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, had to change the y_tick_number which is the number of ticks you want to show on on the y axis. Just had to give it something better to create the divisible outcomes to not be decimals